# Issue with python -m chatterbot --version

Tags: python, terminal, pip, chatterbot

**Could you just help me solve this problem?**

C:\Users\Kacper>py -m pip install chatterbot
Requirement already satisfied: chatterbot in c:\users\kacper\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: nltk<4.0,>=3.2 in c:\users\kacper\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from chatterbot) (3.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml<5.2,>=5.1 in c:\users\kacper\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from chatterbot) (5.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pint>=0.8.1 in c:\users\kacper\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from chatterbot) (0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in c:\users\kacper\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from chatterbot) (2019.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil<2.8,>=2.7 in c:\users\kacper\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from chatterbot) (2.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied: spacy<2.2,>=2.1 in c:\users\kacper\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from chatterbot) (2.1.6)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlalchemy<1.4,>=1.3 in c:\users\kacper\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from chatterbot) (1.3.6)
Requirement already satisfied: mathparse<0.2,>=0.1 in c:\users\kacper\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from chatterbot) (0.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\kacper\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from nltk<4.0,>=3.2->chatterbot) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: thinc<7.1.0,>=7.0.8 in c:\users\kacper\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from spacy<2.2,>=2.1->chatterbot) (7.0.8)
Requirement already satisfied: murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0 in c:\users\kacper\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from spacy<2.2,>=2.1->chatterbot) (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: plac<1.0.0,>=0.9.6 in c:\users\kacper\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from spacy<2.2,>=2.1->chatterbot) (0.9.6)
Requirement already satisfied: cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2 in c:\users\kacper\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from spacy<2.2,>=2.1->chatterbot) (2.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: wasabi<1.1.0,>=0.2.0 in c:\users\kacper\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from spacy<2.2,>=2.1->chatterbot) (0.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: blis<0.3.0,>=0.2.2 in c:\users\kacper\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from spacy<2.2,>=2.1->chatterbot) (0.2.4)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0 in c:\users\kacper\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from spacy<2.2,>=2.1->chatterbot) (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15.0 in c:\users\kacper\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from spacy<2.2,>=2.1->chatterbot) (1.16.4)
Requirement already satisfied: srsly<1.1.0,>=0.0.6 in c:\users\kacper\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from spacy<2.2,>=2.1->chatterbot) (0.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: preshed<2.1.0,>=2.0.1 in c:\users\kacper\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from spacy<2.2,>=2.1->chatterbot) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.10.0 in c:\users\kacper\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from thinc<7.1.0,>=7.0.8->spacy<2.2,>=2.1->chatterbot) (4.32.1)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\kacper\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy<2.2,>=2.1->chatterbot) (1.24.2)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\kacper\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy<2.2,>=2.1->chatterbot) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\kacper\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy<2.2,>=2.1->chatterbot) (2019.6.16)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in c:\users\kacper\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy<2.2,>=2.1->chatterbot) (2.8)

**This is what I get after chatterbot --version**

C:\Users\Kacper>py -m chatterbot --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kacper\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "**main**", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\Kacper\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Kacper\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\chatterbot__main__.py", line 20, in 
    print(get_chatterbot_version())
  File "C:\Users\Kacper\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\chatterbot__main__.py", line 15, in get_chatterbot_version
    return config['chatterbot']['version']
  File "C:\Users\Kacper\Anaconda3\lib\configparser.py", line 959, in **getitem**
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'chatterbot'

Comment: please put your code in `code` tags.

Comment: there is no code. It is just cmd

Comment: even that would be good to have in code tags to improve the visibility

Comment: Could you help me solve it?

Comment: actually I get a similar problem if I do this with pandas. But try to do 
`activate py`
`python -m pip freeze`
and search for chatterbot. The problem is not that chatterbot is not installed but that it has no parameter `--version`

Comment: thank you for your reply. Unfortunately I cannot activate py(there is only base and chatterbot_example)

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with anaconda unfortunately. Please try a normal python interpreter and see if it is a compatibility issue with anaconda or something else. Also please add your OS and python version as there are known differences and compatibility issues sometimes that are specific to them. Also try to use the anaconda command line with `python -m chatterbot`.